# C# WebSocket Server Frame Decoding not working and message unknown opcode

Tags: c#, sockets, google-chrome, websocket

So im developing a Web Socket Server in c# have a Web Socket upgrading correctly, and i'm at the point of receiving frames however i seem to be decoding the frames incorrectly,

Code for handling read from frame

```
bool started = false;
// to write something back.
while (bClientConnected)
{
    try
    {
        msg = this.decryptFrame(client.Client);
        Console.WriteLine("Client Frame Decrypt: " + msg);
        //sWriter.WriteLine("pong!");
        //sWriter.Flush();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection from " + ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString() + " was terminated unkown reason.");
        bClientConnected = false;
        client.Close();
        continue;
    }
    started = true;
}
```

Code for parsing and debugging the Frames:

```
public string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in ba)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    return hex.ToString();
}

private string decryptFrame(Socket sock)
{
    // busy wait untill something is sent
    while (sock.Available == 0) { }

    var header = new byte[6];
    sock.Receive(header);
    var length = header[1] & 127;

    Console.WriteLine("Recived header >> " + this.ByteArrayToString(header));

    var body = new byte[length];
    sock.Receive(body);
    Console.WriteLine("Recived body >> " + this.ByteArrayToString(body));
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        body[i] ^= header[2 + (i & 3)];
    }
    Console.WriteLine("decoded body >> " + this.ByteArrayToString(body));
    string resp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body, 0, length);
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed body >> " + resp);
    return resp;
}
```

The Problem is that chrome frames is instantly showing `(Opcode -1)` in the frames view and the only frame sent to my server is debugged as

```
Recived header >> 88909495d0d4
Recived body >> 977f85bafffbbfa3fab5bfa4f7fab4b1
decoded body >> 03ea556e6b6e6f776e206f70636f6465
Parsed body >> ?Unknown opcode
Client Frame Decrypt: ?Unknown opcode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused as there appears to be a problem with the implementation currently deployed in Chrome & Firefox for some reason the \r\n is not ending the line in the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header so a space is required so something is wrong with the implementation in browsers with regards to `\r\n` on the header

```
"HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
+ "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
+ "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
+ "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + Convert.ToBase64String(
    SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            new Regex("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Match(headerBlock).Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
            )
        )
   ) + " \r\n\r\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

This article is a good start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers

Specifically, I think you are not handling well [the frame length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Decoding_Payload_Length).

> 1. Read bits 9-15 (inclusive) and interpret that as an unsigned
>      integer. If it's 125 or less, then that's the length; you're done.
>      If it's 126, go to step 2. If it's 127, go to step 3.
> 2. Read the next 16 bits and interpret those as an unsigned integer. You're done.
> 3. Read the next 64 bits and interpret those as an unsigned integer
>      (The most significant bit MUST be 0). You're done.

I do not have VS here, but here you go a quirk example:

```
var buffer = new byte[8192];

// put a frame in the buffer
// I am assuming that the frame is complete, starting at byte 0.
// Usually you will have to deal with incomplete frames
FillBuffer(buffer); 

// length is in the second byte
int length = buffer[1]; 

// in the second byte, the first bit enables or disables MASK
// this bit would add a value of +128 (2^7) if enabled
length = (value >= 128 ? value - 128:value); 
if(length == 126) // medium size frame
    length = BitConverter.ToUint16(frame, 2);
else if(length == 127) // big ass frame
    length = BitConverter.ToUint64(frame, 2);
else if(length > 127)
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid frame length {length}");
```

I develop a WebSocket component in C#, you may find the code interesting if you have doubts : https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener

Comment: The problem is that makes it sound so simple, the problem is i can't work at a bit level in C# it's byte level and both 9 and 15 are not at byte positions. 8 bits = 1 byte, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7][8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15] so i have a wrong 8th bit in my byte at position 2

Comment: Thanks for the update, that makes more sense now, can i change buffer to 4(32bits)? to only read the header? as the reason method I'm using Socket.Receive it would be nice if there was a constant byte length for a frame.

Comment: Well they tried to save space when using small frames :) Note that the frame length can be 6, 10 or 14 bytes.

Comment: what is frame supposed to be in this a byte array but of what?